# Discrete functor preserves serre fibrations

Tags: category-theory, model-categories

Consider $Top$ equipped with the Serre's structure and $Set$ with the trivial model structure (All maps fibrations and cofibrations, bijections weak equivalences) and the functor
$D: Set \to Top$ that equips each set with the discrete topology

How can I show that $D$ preserves fibrations? (The fibrations in are the morphisms satisfying the right lifting property with respect to $\{i_0 : D^n \to D^n \times I | \; n > 0\}$ )

Comment: You can forget about the functor and just prove this: any map between discrete topological spaces is a fibration. You will need to use the connectedness of $D^n$ and $D^n \times I$.

Comment: Thanks! This observation actually solved my problem. Should I mark it as answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the discrete space functor $\textbf{Set} \to \textbf{Top}$ is a fully faithful embedding, you can just forget about the functor and prove the following instead:

> Every map between discrete spaces is a fibration.

You can use the fact that the spaces $D^n$ and $D^n \times I$ are connected to prove this.

---

The above argument is morally the same as the following adjointness argument. The discrete space functor $\textbf{Set} \to \textbf{Top}$ has a left adjoint, namely the connected components functor $\pi_0 : \textbf{Top} \to \textbf{Set}$. For formal (= abstract nonsense) reasons, a right adjoint functor preserves fibrations if and only if its left adjoint preserves trivial cofibrations. But $\pi_0 : \textbf{Top} \to \textbf{Set}$ sends weak homotopy equivalences to bijections, so the discrete space functor $\textbf{Set} \to \textbf{Top}$ preserves fibrations.